# Joining three separate models into one result

Tags: mysql, database

I have a Model `Newsfeed` with three children, `NewsfeedImage`, `NewsfeedText`, and `NewsfeedLink`.

Newsfeed

[image: newsfeed data]

NewsfeedImage

[image: image data]

NewsfeedLink

[image: link data]

NewsfeedText

[image: text data]

As you can see from the three child models, each represents a different type of newsfeed object. My question is, how can I `select *` from `Newsfeed` and include each affiliated child models? Desired output (disregard JSON):

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "userId": "1",
    "commentCount": "0",
    "likeCount": "0",
    "updatedAt": "2015-12-13 12:12:32",
    "createdAt": "2015-12-13 12:12:32",
    "newsfeedId": "1",
    "model": "1",
    "imgUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/...",
    "title": "Has anyone..."
}, {
    "id": "1",
    "userId": "1",
    "commentCount": "0",
    "likeCount": "0",
    "updatedAt": "2015-12-13 12:12:32",
    "createdAt": "2015-12-13 12:12:32",
    "newsfeedId": "2",
    "model": "2",
    "linkShort": "http://goo.gl/...",
    "linkLong": "http://www....",
    "title": "Has anyone ...?"
}, {
    "id": "1",
    "userId": "1",
    "commentCount": "0",
    "likeCount": "0",
    "updatedAt": "2015-12-13 12:12:32",
    "createdAt": "2015-12-13 12:12:32",
    "newsfeedId": "3",
    "model": "3",
    "body": "How much ...?",
    "title": "Question ..."
}]
```

I originally attempted to use joins, but the data was intersecting improperly. I appreciate the help, and thank you for taking the time to look at my question.

Comment: You can't use joins nor unions because your columns are different. You can create a view with all the columns And then the columns that contains null values will be discarded reading the json

Answer (score 0):

SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM Newsfeed
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT newsfeedId, model, imgUrl, 
        null AS linkShort, null AS linkLong, null AS body, 
        title
    FROM NewsfeedImage 
    WHERE NewsfeedImage.newsfeedid = Newsfeed.id

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT newsfeedId, model, null AS imgUrl, 
        linkShort, linkLong, null AS body, 
        title
    FROM NewsfeedLink 
    WHERE NewsfeedLink.newsfeedid = Newsfeed.id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT newsfeedId, model, null imgUrl, 
        null AS linkShort, null AS linkLong, body, 
        title
    FROM NewsfeedText 
    WHERE NewsfeedText.newsfeedid = Newsfeed.id

) t
```

And remove fields with `null`s in your program script.